# Python Selenium: Block-Title is not properly verified. (Magento Cloud)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, magento, selenium-webdriver

**Details:**

Currently I am writing within a project based on Magento Cloud test cases with Python-Selenium. So far everything is fine. Currently I only have one problem, which I can't explain anymore.

Actually it's only about the verification of a text. Or the verification of a block title within a profile page.

I would like to secure multiple times, and thus define 2 different test cases.

**issues**

I always get the following message.

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

**The Source**

```
#Verify My Account
        driver.get("https:my-url.de")
        try: self.assertEqual("Account Information", driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='My Account'])[4]/following::strong[1]").text)
        except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
        self.assertEqual("Account Information", driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='My Account'])[4]/following::strong[1]").text)
```

Questions:

- Do I use the correct query?  Apparently no?
- Is it due to Magento
- How can I check these blocks?

  [image: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document]

[image]

Comment: you should try explicit wait for visibility of element before verify/assertion text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant HTML in text format would have helped to construct a canonical answer. However, you were close. To assert the block title within the profile page you have to you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `text` attribute:

  ```
  #Verify My Account
  driver.get("https:my-url.de")
  try: self.assertEqual("Account Information", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "main.page-main#maincontent div.block-dashboard-info > div.block-title strong"))).text)
  except (TimeoutException, AssertionError) as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  #Verify My Account
  driver.get("https:my-url.de")
  try: self.assertEqual("Account Information", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//main[@class='page-main' and @id='maincontent']//div[@class='block-dashboard-info']/div[@class='block-title']//strong"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  except (TimeoutException, AssertionError) as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Please try webdriver wait for visibility of element so the element will get time to load in dom properly, it will prevent it from to become stale element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

        driver.get("https:my-url.de")
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
                try: 
                   accountInfo = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[.='Account Information']")))
                   self.assertEqual("Account Information", accountInfo.text)
                except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
                   self.assertEqual("Account Information", driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='My Account'])[4]/following::strong[1]").text)
```