# Why does Python selenium throw a StaleElementReferenceException when I try to access the text of an element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access the text of an element using selenium with Python. I can access the elements themselves just fine, but when I try to get the text it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # I removed the path for my post, but there is one that works in my actual code
URL = "https://www.costco.com/laptops.html"
driver.get(URL)
prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price")
print([price.text for price in prices])
```

If I run this code I get: **selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**

However, if I were to print out the elements themselves, I have no problem.
I read some previous posts about the stale element exception, but I don't understand why it applies to me in this case. Why would the DOM change when I try to access the text? Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Selenium: Block-Title is not properly verified. (Magento Cloud)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213880/python-selenium-block-title-is-not-properly-verified-magento-cloud)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turn out you just need to wait:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # I removed the path for my post, but there is one that works in my actual code
URL = "https://www.costco.com/laptops.html"
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3)

prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("price")

print([price.text for price in prices])
```

Output:

```
['$1,999.99', '$2,299.99', '', '', '$769.99', '', '$799.99', '$1,449.99', '$1,199.99', '$1,199.99', '$1,999.99', '$1,599.99', '$1,299.99', '$2,299.99', '$1,549.99', '$1,499.99', '$599.99', '$1,699.99', '$1,079.99', '$2,999.99', '$1,649.99', '$1,499.99', '$2,399.99', '$1,499.97', '$1,199.99', '$1,649.99', '$849.99', '']
```

The correct way to do this is to use `WebDriverWait`. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851841/11573842)

---

**Old answer**:

I am not entirely sure why that is happening. But I would suggest you try [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # I removed the path for my post, but there is one that works in my actual code
URL = "https://www.costco.com/laptops.html"
driver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

divs = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"price"})

[div.text.replace("\t",'').replace("\n",'') for div in divs]
```

Output:

```
['$1,099.99',
 '$399.99',
 '$1,199.99',
 '$599.99',
 '$1,049.99',
 '$799.99',
 '$699.99',
 '$949.99',
 '$699.99',
 '$1,999.99',
 '$449.99',
 '$2,699.99',
 '$1,149.99',
 '$1,599.99',
 '$1,049.99',
 '$1,249.99',
 '$299.99',
 '$1,799.99',
 '$749.99',
 '$849.99',
 '$2,299.99',
 '$999.99',
 '$649.99',
 '$799.99']
```

Comment: Do you know why we need to wait? I am sorry, but I do not understand.

Comment: The website takes time to load. So while that is happening if `Selenium` tries to find the elements then it won't be able to find them and give this error.